# Change view & edit route or URL of Entities generated by Drupal Console

Tags: 8, entities, routes, console

I have generated a custom entity using Drupal Console.

```
drupal generate:entity:content
```

However, there is one serious problem. All the default route for the various operation related to that entity are coming under `/admin/..` route. Which prevent non-admins from accessing those pages even if given permission for example to `edit` it.

When I generate an entity called company. My routes are as below:

- View Single Entiy: `/admin/structure/company_entity/{company_entity}`
- Add Entity: `/admin/structure/company_entity/add`
- Edit Entity: `/admin/structure/company_entity/{company_entity}/edit`
- Delete Entity: `/admin/structure/company_entity/{company_entity}/delete`
- List all Enitities: `/admin/structure/company_entity`

Where should we edit the module to override or change these settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to edit the entity class's annotation, at e.g. module_name/src/Entity/FooEntity.php.

This is an example of what you need from the [Node](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!node!src!Entity!Node.php/class/Node/8.2.x) entity class:

```
links = {
    "canonical" = "/node/{node}",
    "delete-form" = "/node/{node}/delete",
    "edit-form" = "/node/{node}/edit",
    "version-history" = "/node/{node}/revisions",
    "revision" = "/node/{node}/revisions/{node_revision}/view",
}
```

You'll probably need to rebuild cache for the changes to be reflected.

Comment: I figured it out a while ago and was about to post an answer. Great to see it already answered. :)